# Fastest way to compare rows of two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two pandas dataframes, A and B.

A is 1000 rows x 500 columns, filled with binary values indicating either presence or absence.

B is 1024 rows x 10 columns, and is a full iteration of 0's and 1's, hence having 1024 rows.

I am trying to find which rows in A, at a particular 10 columns of A, correspond with a given row in B. I need the whole row to match up, rather than element by element.

For example, I would want

```
A[(A.ix[:,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)==(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)).all(axis=1)]
```

To return something that rows `(3,5,8,11,15)` in A match up with that `(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)` row of B at those particular columns `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

And I want to do this over every row in B.
The best way I could figure out to do this was:

```
import numpy as np
for i in B:
    B_array = np.array(i)
    Matching_Rows = A[(A.ix[:,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)] == B_array).all(axis=1)]
    Matching_Rows_Index = Matching_Rows.index
```

This isn't terrible for one instance, but I use it in a while loop that runs around 20,000 times; therefore, it slows it down quite a bit.

I have been messing around with DataFrame.apply to no avail. Could map work better?

I was just hoping someone saw something obviously more efficient as I am fairly new to python.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: There might be multiple matches of B in a single row of A. So, do you want at least one match in a particular row of A? Or are you looking for matches between col1-col10 only from A judging by the posted code?

Comment: What are you going to do with the matching rows? It seems to me like you could just avoid B altogether and use `groupby` on your 10 columns of interest of A.

Comment: I am going to calculate an entropy value based on the matching rows.

Comment: Maybe you can just do `A.groupby(column_list).apply(my_entropy_function)` then. Take a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - output are indexes of `B` which are equal in `A` in custom columns:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,0,1,1],
                  'B':[0,0,1,1],
                  'C':[1,0,1,1],
                  'D':[1,1,1,0],
                  'E':[1,1,0,1]})

print (A)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  0  1  1  1
1  0  0  0  1  1
2  1  1  1  1  0
3  1  1  1  0  1

B = pd.DataFrame({'0':[1,0,1],
                  '1':[1,0,1],
                  '2':[1,0,0]})

print (B)
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  0
2  1  1  0
```

```
print (pd.merge(B.reset_index(), 
                A.reset_index(), 
                left_on=B.columns.tolist(), 
                right_on=A.columns[[0,1,2]].tolist(),
                suffixes=('_B','_A')))

   index_B  0  1  2  index_A  A  B  C  D  E
0        0  1  1  1        2  1  1  1  1  0
1        0  1  1  1        3  1  1  1  0  1
2        1  0  0  0        1  0  0  0  1  1    

print (pd.merge(B.reset_index(), 
                A.reset_index(), 
                left_on=B.columns.tolist(), 
                right_on=A.columns[[0,1,2]].tolist(),
                suffixes=('_B','_A'))[['index_B','index_A']])    

   index_B  index_A
0        0        2
1        0        3
2        1        1
```

Comment: thank you! This, along with other changes to my code, brought my run-time down from 10 hours to 10 minutes.

Comment: @jezrael. may i did not understand the question correctly, but with the above solution, how will you compare rows in A that are outside the range specified in the solution (like say cols 22:32 in A correspond with row 7 in B)? As per my understanding you have hard-cored the lookup list of cols in A for comparison purpose (ie cols 0,1,2)

Answer (score 4):

We can abuse the fact that both dataframes have binary values `0` or `1` by collapsing the relevant columns from `A` and all columns from `B` into `1D` arrays each, when considering each row as a sequence of binary numbers that could be converted to decimal number equivalents. This should reduce the problem set considerably, which would help with performance. Now, after getting those `1D` arrays, we can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to look for matches from `B` in `A` and finally [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) on it to get the matching indices.

Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
# Setup 1D arrays corresponding to selected cols from A and entire B
S = 2**np.arange(10)
A_ID = np.dot(A[range(1,11)],S)
B_ID = np.dot(B,S)

# Look for matches that exist from B_ID in A_ID, whose indices 
# would be desired row indices that have matched from B
out_row_idx = np.where(np.in1d(A_ID,B_ID))[0]
```

Sample run -

```
In [157]: # Setup dataframes A and B with rows 0, 4 in A having matches from B
     ...: A_arr = np.random.randint(0,2,(10,14))
     ...: B_arr = np.random.randint(0,2,(7,10))
     ...: 
     ...: B_arr[2] = A_arr[4,1:11]
     ...: B_arr[4] = A_arr[4,1:11]
     ...: B_arr[5] = A_arr[0,1:11]
     ...: 
     ...: A = pd.DataFrame(A_arr)
     ...: B = pd.DataFrame(B_arr)
     ...: 

In [158]: S = 2**np.arange(10)
     ...: A_ID = np.dot(A[range(1,11)],S)
     ...: B_ID = np.dot(B,S)
     ...: out_row_idx = np.where(np.in1d(A_ID,B_ID))[0]
     ...: 

In [159]: out_row_idx
Out[159]: array([0, 4])
```

Comment: So I have a follow-up question on this, I really like the efficiency of this method, but when I run it using my dataframes, `out_row_idx` just returns an array of size 1000 that just contains all the indices of A, do you have any input as to why that might be?

Comment: `S = 2**np.arange(10); 
            A_ID = np.dot(A[X],S);
            B_ID = np.dot(B,S);
            out_row_idx = np.where(np.in1d(A_ID,B_ID))[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pandas by using loc or ix and telling it to find the rows where the ten columns are all equal. Like this:

```
A.loc[(A[1]==B[1]) & (A[2]==B[2]) & (A[3]==B[3]) & A[4]==B[4]) & (A[5]==B[5]) & (A[6]==B[6]) & (A[7]==B[7]) & (A[8]==B[8]) & (A[9]==B[9]) & (A[10]==B[10])]
```

This is quite ugly in my opinion but it will work and gets rid of the loop so it should be significantly faster. I wouldn't be surprised if someone could come up with a more elegant way of coding the same operation.

Answer (score 1):

In this special case, your rows of 10 zeros and ones can be interpreted as 10 digit binaries.  If B is in order, then it can be interpreted as a range from 0 to 1023.  In this case, all we need to do is take A's rows in 10 column chunks and calculate what its binary equivalent is.

I'll start by defining a range of powers of two so I can do matrix multiplication with it.

```
twos = pd.Series(np.power(2, np.arange(10)))
```

Next, I'll relabel A's columns into a MultiIndex and `stack` to get my chunks of 10.

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, .5, (1000, 500)))
A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip((A.columns / 10).tolist(), (A.columns % 10).tolist()))
A_ = A.stack(0)

A_.head()
```

[image]

Finally, I'll multiply `A_` with `twos` to get integer representation of each row and `unstack`.

```
A_.dot(twos).unstack()
```

[image]

This is now a 1000 x 50 DataFrame where each cell represents which of B's rows we matched for that particular 10 column chunk for that particular row of A.  There isn't even a need for B.