# Comparing rows of two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is a continuation of my question. [Fastest way to compare rows of two pandas dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267763/fastest-way-to-compare-rows-of-two-pandas-dataframes/38270174#38270174)

I have two dataframes `A` and `B`:

`A` is 1000 rows x 500 columns, filled with binary values indicating either presence or absence.

For a condensed example:

```
    A   B   C   D   E  
0   0   0   0   1   0  
1   1   1   1   1   0  
2   1   0   0   1   1  
3   0   1   1   1   0
```

`B` is 1024 rows x 10 columns, and is a full iteration from 0 to 1023 in binary form.

Example:

```
     0   1   2  
0    0   0   0  
1    0   0   1   
2    0   1   0  
3    0   1   1  
4    1   0   0
5    1   0   1
6    1   1   0 
7    1   1   1
```

I am trying to find which rows in `A`, at a particular 10 columns of `A`, correspond with each row of `B`.

Each row of `A[My_Columns_List]` is guaranteed to be somewhere in `B`, but not every row of `B` will match up with a row in `A[My_Columns_List]`

For example, I want to show that for columns `[B,D,E]` of `A`,

rows `[1,3]` of A match up with row `[6]` of `B`,

row `[0]` of A matches up with row `[2]` of `B`,

row `[2]` of A matches up with row `[3]` of `B`.

I have tried using:

```
pd.merge(B.reset_index(), A.reset_index(),
left_on = B.columns.tolist(),
right_on =A.columns[My_Columns_List].tolist(), 
suffixes = ('_B','_A')))
```

This works, but I was hoping that this method would be faster:

```
S = 2**np.arange(10)
A_ID = np.dot(A[My_Columns_List],S)
B_ID = np.dot(B,S)
out_row_idx = np.where(np.in1d(A_ID,B_ID))[0]
```

But when I do this, `out_row_idx` returns an array containing all the indices of `A`, which doesn't tell me anything.
I think this method will be faster, but I don't know why it returns an array from 0 to 999.
Any input would be appreciated!

Also, credit goes to @jezrael and @Divakar for these methods.

Comment: Please post example DataFrames and what result you are trying to achieve from those examples.

Comment: For clarity in future, don't call the dataframes `A`, `B`, when dataframe `A` also contains columns `A`, `B`, `C`... call the dataframes `df1, df2` or `dfa, dfb`. Also in Python we use PEP-8 naming convention for variables, so not `A_ID` but `a_id` or even better, `id_a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll stick by my initial answer but maybe explain better.

You are asking to compare 2 pandas dataframes.  Because of that, I'm going to build dataframes.  I may use numpy, but my inputs and outputs will be dataframes.

#### Setup

You said we have a a 1000 x 500 array of ones and zeros.  Let's build that.

```
A_init = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, .5, (1000, 500)))
A_init.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(A_init.shape[1]/10), range(10)])
A = A_init
```

In addition, I gave `A` a `MultiIndex` to easily group by columns of 10.

#### Solution

This is very similar to @Divakar's answer with one minor difference that I'll point out.

For one group of 10 ones and zeros, we can treat it as a bit array of length 8.  We can then calculate what it's integer value is by taking the dot product with an array of powers of 2.

```
twos = 2 ** np.arange(10)
```

I can execute this for every group of 10 ones and zeros in one go like this

```
AtB = A.stack(0).dot(twos).unstack()
```

I `stack` to get a row of 50 groups of 10 into columns in order to do the dot product more elegantly.  I then brought it back with the `unstack`.

I now have a 1000 x 50 dataframe of numbers that range from 0-1023.

Assume `B` is a dataframe with each row one of 1024 unique combinations of ones and zeros. `B` should be sorted like `B = B.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)`.

This is the part I think I failed at explaining last time.  Look at

```
AtB.loc[:2, :2]
```

[image]

That value in the `(0, 0)` position, `951` means that the first group of 10 ones and zeros in the first row of `A` matches the row in `B` with the index `951`.  That's what you want!!!  Funny thing is, I never looked at B.  You know why, B is irrelevant!!! It's just a goofy way of representing the numbers from 0 to 1023.  This is the difference with my answer, I'm ignoring `B`.  Ignoring this useless step should save time.

These are all functions that take two dataframes `A` and `B` and returns a dataframe of indices where `A` matches `B`.  Spoiler alert, I'll ignore `B` completely.

```
def FindAinB(A, B):
    assert A.shape[1] % 10 == 0, 'Number of columns in A is not a multiple of 10'
    rng = np.arange(A.shape[1])
    A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(A.shape[1]/10), range(10)])

    twos = 2 ** np.arange(10)

    return A.stack(0).dot(twos).unstack()
```

---

```
def FindAinB2(A, B):
    assert A.shape[1] % 10 == 0, 'Number of columns in A is not a multiple of 10'
    rng = np.arange(A.shape[1])
    A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(A.shape[1]/10), range(10)])
    # use clever bit shifting instead of dot product with powers
    # questionable improvement
    return (A.stack(0) << np.arange(10)).sum(1).unstack()
```

---

I'm channelling my inner @Divakar (read, this is stuff I've learned from Divakar)

```
def FindAinB3(A, B):
    assert A.shape[1] % 10 == 0, 'Number of columns in A is not a multiple of 10'
    a = A.values.reshape(-1, 10)
    a = np.einsum('ij->i', a << np.arange(10))
    return pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(A.shape[0], -1), A.index)
```

---

#### Minimalist One Liner

```
f = lambda A: pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('ij->i', A.values.reshape(-1, 10) << np.arange(10)).reshape(A.shape[0], -1), A.index)
```

Use it like

```
f(A)
```

---

#### Timing

FindAinB3 is an order of magnitude faster

[image]

Comment: Hey @piRSquared, I did really like the efficiency of your answer; however, I kept getting an error: `TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()` and couldn't figure out the issue. I was worried that it was a python 3 vs. 2 problem, but I will look over this and see if I am able to figure it out. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes I am. From what I understand, zip returns a generator in Python 3 as opposed to a list.

Comment: I tried the second function and it worked, I took your advice about ignoring B, I just didn't know how to do it otherwise before. Also, I had to use `A.columns = pd.Multindex.from_product([range(int(A.shape[1]/10),range(10)])` due to a float error.

Comment: I should've been more specific, how can I edit the function so that I specify which columns of A I am looking at? Rather than taking groups of them.

Comment: @GarrettMiller you should just pass `A` with the columns you want into the function.

Comment: @Divakar how'd you like my `np.einsum` though?  That's all you.

Comment: Loved that part, it's one of the best things with NumPy! Nothing beats dot prod though.

Comment: Fantastic! This is well above my knowledge of python and I will have to read some documentation on it to learn more. Thank you! For some reason, I had to pass A with my columns in reverse order. ex: `['E','D','B']` rather than `['B','D','E']` to achieve my previous results.